# What signal should I expect when my program exits normally?

Tags: linux

I have a shared object that I have written which I link to an Linux executable (say a game for example). Now when the program finishes (game over!), what kind of signal handler should I have in my shared object that I created in order to perform some cleanup activities?

Please remember that I DO NOT have control over the Linux executable, it is a game that I simply download from the Internet and run it by linking it to my shared object. When the game finishes, I want to be able to catch that event and do some cleanup activities.

Have I made my question clear? Any ideas?

Thanks,
Krishna

Comment: How exactly do you _run_ it by "linking it to your shared object"?

Comment: command-prompt> (LD_PRELOAD="./my_shared_object.so" ./my_game)

Answer (score 1):

if you run the game as a child process, you'll get SIGCHLD (17) when the other process ends.

Comment: Hi, No. I won't be running the game as a child process but rather as mentioned linking my shared object to the executable using LD_PRELOAD.

Answer (score 1):

If the main application uses the standard C library, then you can make use of the `atexit(3)` function to register a function to be called when the application exits.

There are a number of cases where the function will not be called though (abnormal termination through signals, a call to `_exit(2)`, etc), so check the man page to see if all your use cases are covered.

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for taking the time to respond to this question. Your suggestion seems very relevant. Yes, my executable(or main application or game - whatever you want to call) is a program developed using C. So I should be fine using atexit(3) I guess. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can't do this from *within* the process. (Software can't have dying wishes.)

However, you could run the existing game process inside a wrapper script or something that runs another program after the game finishes:

```
#!/bin/sh

run_game
perform_cleanup_activity
```

Comment: Hi, Your reply is interesting. But the need is to "trampoline" OpenGL API calls made by the game (which I refer to as executable) using my shared object. And when the game finishes, I want to write time taken for each function call to a file on the disk. If I do this activity "while the game is running" I might get incorrect values because it takes time to do file IO.

Comment: @Kris Retro Virus: Perhaps you could open a shared memory area where your `.so` writes performance information at runtime. Then, have a completely separate application that opens the same shared memory area, reads the data, and formats and writes it to disk. This will also reduce the dependencies that your `.so` relies on (since it won't have to do formatting or file I/O itself). Also, you can get live performance data while the game is running.

Comment: Hi Greg, that seems like a nice idea too. I will certainly give that a try. I think this is similar to what I too had in mind i.e. using pipes...